# Can I change the color of Trello Boards?

Tags: trello-boards

Are they always blue?

I'm using it for Christmas and would like a more seasonal color.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to achieving a seasonal colour effect is to use the labels for cards on a given board. It seems that the label colors themselves are not editable; you can see them if you click on the arrow beside the board name when viewing the board.

If you go to your account settings and change the Accessibility option to - Enable Color Blind Friendly Mode - some of the labels get a dotted effect which sort of looks like Christmas tree lights.